# 9 Deaths of the Ninja

Tags: code-golf, number, simulation

*Inspired by [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=26561376#26561376) conversation in chat.*

Your goal in this challenge is to emulate a ninja and count how many deaths he has left.

### Specs

You ninja starts out with 9 deaths left. He also gets an integral starting health as an input.

Then, he takes as input a list of events in his life that alter his health. These can be negative, positive, or zero integers.

At any point, if his health reaches at or below zero, he loses a life and his health goes back to the starting health.

Your program should report the number of deaths he has left. If he has zero or less left, you should output `dead` instead.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

### Test Cases

```
3, [] -> 9
100, [-20, 5, -50, 15, -30, -30, 10] -> 8
10, [-10, -10, -10, -10] -> 5
10, [-10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10] -> dead
0, [] -> dead
0, [1] -> dead
100, [10, -100] -> 9
```

Comment: YAY!!! My chat post is linked!!! :P

Comment: Looks like I'm in trouble...

Comment: So the order of events is "die if <=0, read a number, add to total, repeat"?

Comment: @ThomasKwa yeah, but the dying can happen multiple times

Comment: Can ninjas regenerate like time lords? Please?

Comment: Can the starting health be negative?

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
»0o⁴+
;@ñ\<1S_9«0N“dead”×?
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=wrswb-KBtCsKO0DDsVw8MVNfOcKrME7igJxkZWFk4oCdw5c_&input=&args=Wy0yMCwgNSwgLTUwLCAxNSwgLTMwLCAtMzAsIDEwXQ+MTAw)

#### How it works

```
;@ñ\<1S_9«0N“dead”×?  Main link. Input: e (events), h (initial health)

;@                    Prepend h to e.
  ñ\                  Reduce the resulting array by the next, dyadic link.
                      This returns the array of intermediate results.
    <1                Check each intermediate value for non-positivity.
      S               Sum. This calculates the number of event deaths.
       _9             Subtract 9 from the result.
         «0           Take the minimum of the result and 0. This yields 0 if no
                      lives are left, the negated amount of lives otherwise.
                   ?  Conditional:
                  ×     If the product of the minimum and h is non-zero:
           N              Return the negated minimum.
            “dead”      Else, return "dead".


»0o⁴+                 Dyadic helper link. Arguments: x, y

»0                    Take the maximum of x and 0.
                      This yields x if x > 0 and 0 otherwise.
  o⁴                  Take the logical OR of the result and the second input (h).
    +                 Take the sum of the result and y.
```

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Dennis wins

Answer (score 7):

## Japt, <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 32 bytes

```
U¬©(9-Vf@T=X+(T¬²ªU)<1} l)¬²ª`Ü%
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VaypKDktVmZAVD1YKyhUrLKqVSk8MX0gbCmssqpg3CU=&input=MTAsIFstMTAsIC0xMCwgLTEwLCAtMTAsIC0xMCwgLTEwLCAtMTAsIC0xMCwgLTEwXQ==)

#### How it works

While trying to golf this last night (away from a computer, no less), I ran across an interesting replacement for `>0`: `¬`. On numbers, this takes the square root, which returns `NaN` for negative numbers. `NaN` is falsy, so this returns exactly the same truthily/falsily as `>0`.

Extending this trick a little further, we can reset T to U iff it's `>=0` in only five bytes: `T¬²ªU`. How does this work? Let's take a look:

```
T    ¬      ²       ªU
     sqrt   square  if falsy, set to U (JS's || operator)
4    2      4       4
7   ~2.646  7       7
0    0      0       U
-4   NaN    NaN     U
-7   NaN    NaN     U
```

As you can see, `T¬²` returns `NaN` if `T` is negative; otherwise, it returns `T`. Since `NaN` and `0` are both falsy, this provides an easy way to reset the ninja's health with `ªU`. This trick is also used to return the ninja's lives left if that number is positive, or `"dead"` if negative.

Putting this all together:

```
           // Implicit: U = starting health, V = events, T = 0
U¬©        // If U is positive,
Vf@     }  // Filter out the items X in V that return truthily from this function:
 T=X+      //  Set T to X plus
 (T¬²ªU)   //   If T is positive, T; otherwise, U.
           //  This keeps a running total of the ninja's health, resetting upon death.
 <1        //  Return (T < 1).
9-    l)   // Take the length of the resulting array and subtract from 9.
           // This returns the number of lives the ninja has left.
¬²         // If the result is negative, set it to NaN.
ª`Ü%       // If the result of EITHER of the two parts above is falsy, return "dead".
           //  (`Ü%` is "dead" compressed.)
           // Otherwise, return the result of the middle part (lives left).
           // Implicit: output last expression
```

If the input is guaranteed to be non-negative, or even positive, we can golf of 1 or 4 bytes:

```
U©(9-Vf@T=X+(T¬²ªU)<1} l)¬²ª`Ü%  // U is non-negative
9-Vf@T=X+(T¬²ªU)<1} l)¬²ª`Ü%     // U is positive
```

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>62 60</s> 58 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
(a,b,d=9,l=a)=>b.map(i=>l=l+i<1?d--&&a:l+i,a)|d<1?"dead":d
```

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D%20(a%2Cb%2Cd%3D9)%3D%3E(b.reduce((l%2Ci)%3D%3El%2Bi%3C1%3F(d--%2Ca)%3Al%2Bi%2Ca)%2Cd%3C1%3F%22dead%22%3Ad)%3B%0A%0Af(%20100%2C%20%5B-20%2C%205%2C%20-50%2C%2015%2C%20-30%2C%20-30%2C%2010%5D%20)) (All browsers work)

### Explanation

```
(a,b,    // a = 1st input, b = 2nd input
 d=9)=>  // Lives counter

  (b.reduce((l,i)=>     // Loop through all the health changes
    l+i<1                 // If (health + health change) < 1
    ?(d--,a)              // Decrease life, reset health
    :l+i                  // Return new health
  ,a)                   // Sets starting health to `a`
  ,d<1?        // Lives is less than 1
   "dead":d);  // Output "dead" otherwise lives left
```

Comment: Would `d--&&a` work, or `b.reduce(...)&&d<1?"dead":d`?

Comment: `map` beats `reduce` in most scenarios: `(a,b,d=9,l=a)=>b.map(i=>l=l+i<1?d--&&a:l+i)&&d<1?"dead":d` is 57.

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks, I don't think `.reduce(...)&&` would work because of `.reduce` returns `0`, it won't work.

Comment: Would `(a,b,d=9,l=a)=>b.map(i=>l=l+i<1?d--&&a:l+i,a)|d<1?"dead":d` work instead?

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 35 bytes

```
q~_@{+_1<{W$}&}/](\,_A<@*A@-"dead"?
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX5fQHsrXzE8e1ckfSZ9L10oXCxfQTxAKkFALSJkZWFkIj8&input=Wy0yMCA1IC01MCAxNSAtMzAgLTMwIDEwXSAxMDA)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>81</s> <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```
p l i h a|l<1="dead"|i<1=p(l-1)h h a|[]<-a=show l|x:y<-a=p l(i+x)h y
p 10 0
```

Usage example: `p 10 0 100 [-20, 5, -50, 15, -30, -30, 10]` -> `"8"`

Answer (score 1):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/teascript), <s>36 34</s> 31 bytes

```
yR#l+i<1?e─·x:l+i,x);e≥0?e:D`Ü%
```

Similar to my JavaScript answer. the last 4 characters are the decompression of the string "dead".

TeaScript's online interpreter doesn't support array input so you're going to need to open the console, and run this by typing:

```
TeaScript( `yR#l+i<1?(e─,x):l+i,x);─e>0?e:D\`Ü%` ,[
  10, [-10, -10, -10, -10]
],{},TEASCRIPT_PROPS);
```

#### Explanation

```
      // Implicit: x = 1st input, y = 2nd input
yR#   // Reduce over 2nd input
  l+i<1?  // If pending health is less then 1
  (e─,x): // then, decrease life counter, reset health
  l+i     // else, modify health
,x);  // Set starting health
─e>0? // Ninja is alive?
e:    // Output lives left
D`Ü%  // Decompress and output "dead"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 32

```
 u+?>GZG&=hZQH+E0Q?&Q<Z9-9Z"dead
```

Note that there is a leading space. This probably isn't the best approach, but it was the first thing that came to mind. It reduces over input by adding the values to the ninja's health, and incrementing a counter and resetting the health when it drops below zero. We add a zero to the end of the list to count if the last change kills the ninja, and then just do some checking to see if the ninja is dead. The zero starting health case is hard coded.

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%20u%2B%3F%3EGZG%26%3DhZQH%2BE0Q%3F%26Q%3CZ9-9Z%22dead&input=3%0A%5B%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A%5B%5D%0A100%0A%5B-20%2C%205%2C%20-50%2C%2015%2C%20-30%2C%20-30%2C%2010%5D%0A10%0A%5B-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%5D%0A10%0A%5B-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%2C%20-10%5D%0A0%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%5B1%5D%0A100%0A%5B10%2C%20-100%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 32

```
9yi"@+t0>~?x1-y]]g*wxt0>~?x'dead'
```

### Explanation

```
9        # push 9
y        # duplicate 2nd value to top (there is none -> get it from input first)
i        # get input and push it
```

The stack now looks like this (for input `100, [-20, 5, -50, 15, -30, -30, 10]`):

```
100        9        100        [-20, 5, -50, 15, -30, -30, 10]

reload   deaths    health
value    left
```

Pop the array and loop

```
"            ]    # loop
 @+               # add to health
   t0>~?    ]     # if health is zero or less
        x1-y      # delete health counter, decrement life counter, reload health
```

If the health is zero, set death counter to zero. Special case handling for `initial health = 0`.

```
g        # health to bool
*        # multiply with death counter
```

Delete the reload value from stack

```
wx
```

If the death counter is zero or less, delete it and print 'dead' instead.

```
t0>~?x'dead'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, <strike>82</strike> <strike>66</strike> <strike>55</strike> 106 bytes

*<strike>Thanks to @RikerW for -16 bytes.</strike>:(*

*<strike>Thanks to @Maltysen for -11 bytes.</strike> :(*

```
i=input;h=[i()]*9;d=i()
if 0==h[0]:print'dead';exit()
for x in d:
 h[0]+=x
 if h[0]<=0:h=h[1:]
y=len(h)
print['dead',y][y!=0]
```

First type health, then enter, then events in list form.

Answer (score 0):

### C# 207

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){int h=int.Parse(a[0]),H=h,l=9,i=1;if(a.Length!=1){for(;i<a.Length;i++){H+=int.Parse(a[i]);if(H<=0){l--;H=h;}}}System.Console.Write(h==0?"dead":l<=0?"dead":l.ToString());}}
```

Takes the input through argument stream. The first argument is the amount of health and all the rest is the list of events.

Readable / ungolfed version

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[]a)
    {
        int health = int.Parse(a[0]);
        int Health = health;
        int lives = 9;

        if(a.Length!=1)
        {
            for (int i = 1;i < a.Length;i++)
            {
                Health += int.Parse(a[i]);
                if (Health <= 0)
                {
                    lives--;
                    Health = health;
                }
            }
        }

        System.Console.Write(health == 0 ? "dead" : lives <= 0 ? "dead" : lives.ToString());
    }
}
```

Examples:

- CSharp.exe 3  =>  9
- CSharp.exe 100 -20 5 -50 15 -30 -30 10    =>   8

(Psst.) CSharp.exe is name used as an example. You have to call like this in reality: [program_name.exe] arguments, without the square parentheses.